# Difference Between toPredicate() Method and And/Or/Not/Where in JPA Criteria API Specification<>

Tags: spring-data-jpa, jpa-criteria

I am now exploring the JPA Criteria API for creating the dynamic queries and type safe queries. I am exploring how to use Specification. When I am exploring I found that `toPredicate()` method using to create where clause for the query referenced by the entity. Also exploring about And/Or/Not and where in Specification.

Actually if `toPredicate()` mMethod creating the where clause, then why we using the method "Where"? what is the role of other method when comparing `toPredicate()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you implement a `Specification` from scratch you implement `toPredicate`.

If you already have one or more `Specification`s you can use `and`, `or`, and `not` to combine them into a new specification.

For example, given two specifications `isVip` and `placedAnOrderLastMonth` you can combine them as such:

```
shouldReceiveNagMail = isVip.and(not(placedAnOrderLastMonth));
```

The `where` method is just syntactic sugar that people might like to use to make the code more readable. It just returns essentially the same `Specification`;